# Improve execution time of data import from google sheets to a MySQL table

Tags: google-apps-script, jdbc, google-sheets

I have one large google sheet import that I am working on by breaking it down into smaller chunks for easier processing and this used to work fine until recently when the number of records grew significantly throwing off my script. The sheet has some 40 odd columns and each batch I execute is limited to 500 records and the execution time to process these records is ~4 minutes. I am exploring different options where I could bring down the execution time. The connection is getting closed if the execution were to run even longer than an hour. My idea is to optimize this code so it does not take too long to execute each batch. Is there a faster way to approach this bulk load in jdbc.

```
var address = 'database_IP_address';
var rootPwd = 'root_password';
var user = 'user_name';
var userPwd = 'user_password';
var db = 'database_name';

var root = 'root';
var instanceUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://' + address;
var dbUrl = instanceUrl + '/' + db;

function googleSheetsToMySQL() {   

  var RecId;
  var Code;
  var ProductDescription;
  var Price;

  var dbconnection = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, root, rootPwd);
  var statement = dbconnection.createStatement();
  var googlesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('product'); 
  var data = googlesheet.getDataRange().getValues();  

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
  RecId = data[i][0];
  Code = data[i][1];
  ProductDescription = data[i][2];
  Price = data[i][3];

  var sql = "{call [dbo].[sp_googlesheetstotable](?,?,?,?)}";  
  statement = dbconnection.prepareCall(sql);  
  statement.setString(1, RecId);
  statement.setString(2, Code);
  statement.setString(3, ProductDescription);
  statement.setString(4, Price);
  statement.executeUpdate();  
  }

  statement.close();
  dbconnection.close();
}
```

Comment: Hi there - Stackoverflow isn't the proper forum for code optimisation, more for issues with getting code to work. I suggest you try posting [on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as this is more the appropriate forum for this.

Comment: Or even potentially [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)